# Invoke on member object raises exception c++/cli

Tags: .net, reflection, c++-cli

I am having reflection issues with c++/CLI. Notice in the class A below there are two methods func1 and func2. Both these methods are trying to call Invoke on the same object and the same method.

1. func1 calls invoke using **an object and method info that were created in A's constructor**. when func1 call invoke I get an exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetException' with Additional information: Object does not match target type.
2. func2 calls invoke by doing all the initializations inside the function body - func2 works just fine.

If someone can maybe give me an idea what I'm doing wrong that would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Diagnostics;

#include <msclr/auto_gcroot.h>
using msclr::auto_gcroot;


public class A
{
    private:
        auto_gcroot<System::Reflection::MethodInfo^> m;
        auto_gcroot<Object^> h;
    public:
        A()
        {
            System::Reflection::Assembly^ assem = System::Reflection::Assembly::LoadFrom( "d:\\myManaged.dll" );

            Type^ t = assem->GetType("PTG.PtgScanalyzerForm");
            h = Activator::CreateInstance(t);
            m = t->GetMethod("Show", Type::EmptyTypes);
        }

        void func1()
        {
            try
            {
                Type^ t = h->GetType();
                m->Invoke(h, nullptr);
            }
            catch (Exception^ e)
            {
                // invoke throws an exception
            }
        }

        void func2()
        {
            System::Reflection::Assembly^ assem = System::Reflection::Assembly::LoadFrom( "d:\\myManaged.dll" );

            Type^ t = assem->GetType("PTG.PtgScanalyzerForm");
            Object^ h = Activator::CreateInstance(t);

            System::Reflection::MethodInfo^ m1 = t->GetMethod("Show", Type::EmptyTypes);

            m1->Invoke(h, nullptr);
            // this works!

        }


};


int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{

    Debug::WriteLine("main");

    A a;
    a.func1();
    a.func2();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Stop using auto_gcroot<>, you don't understand how it works.  It was only useful 10 years ago.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant - my first question on SO and you are the first responder so thanks. How then do you add a managed member to a non-managed class like that? Can you post an example or send a link?

Comment: There's not a scrap of native code in this native class.  It should be a `ref class`.  Whatever code needs a reference to it should use `gcroot<>`.  Which is none in your snippet.  Roughly.

Comment: he context is a bit wider-the above is stripped down version-sorry if it confuses. I have a win32 (non cli) c++ app that statically links with a cli/c++ lib. The lib has two classes - one is managed, one is not managed. The win32 code calls the unmanaged part of the lib and then forwards the calls to the managed part. Class "A" in the above example is the managed. All this worked quite well when I had  reference in visual studio setup with the managed componenet I'm bridging to. But I now need to not use the reference and load the library manually which is where I ran into problems

Comment: btw, [this is the link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/soultech/archive/2010/07/27/cli-c_2b002b00_-to-c_2300_-hello-world.aspx) to where the original came from:

Comment: Sorry for late answer anyway I think (but I admit I didn't try your code so I just guess) that compiler simply boxes `auto_gcroot<>`. Change `m->Invoke(h, nullptr);` in `func1()` to `m->Invoke(h.get(), nullptr);` (note `.get()` to extract contained object). In _original_ version **I suppose** it's trying to invoke method `m` on `h` itself instead of on its contained value.